# automaticly change variable in where clause

Tags: mysql, variables, date, where-clause

The code i use gives me the correct information based on a date in a where clause. I want to have the same information on other dates. So now I have to change the date myself and run the code, copy/paste it somewhere else and start over again with a new date. That takes a lot of work if i want the information for every day of the year. Is it possible to automaticly change the date in the where clause and what is the best or easiest way to do that?

```
Select t4.Count, t4.Status
From(
    SELECT count(l.VoerID) as Count, l.Datum, l.Status, l.LogID
      FROM (
             SELECT k.VoerID, k.Datum, MAX(k.LogID) AS LogID
               FROM DB.LogStatus k
                Where Datum < '2013-07-01'
              GROUP BY k.VoerID
           ) m
      JOIN DB.LogStatus l
        ON l.VoerID = m.VoerID AND l.LogID = m.LogID
    Where status in ('B','IN1','IN2''V','Reserv')
    Group by Status
)t4
```

EDIT:

original table (selected on one VoerID) (table consist of thousands of VoerID's)

> LogID Datum   UserID  Status  Time    VoerID
>
> 1299772   2013-04-17  259 N   14:09:11    50174
>
> 1319774   2013-05-23  68  B   11:19:17    50174
>
> 1320038   2013-05-23  197 IN1 16:53:30    50174
>
> 1322002   2013-05-28  68  IN2 09:22:32    50174
>
> 1325052   2013-05-31  161 G   09:00:59    50174
>
> 1325166   2013-05-31  10  400 09:15:12    50174
>
> 1325182   2013-05-31  10  V   09:30:07    50174
>
> 1325208   2013-05-31  10  V   09:45:06    50174
>
> 1325406   2013-05-31  10  Reserv  11:45:06    50174
>
> 1325522   2013-05-31  10  Reserv  12:15:06    50174
>
> 1325954   2013-05-31  10  Reserv  15:15:13    50174
>
> 1328474   2013-06-05  10  Reserv  13:15:06    50174
>
> 1329230   2013-06-06  10  Reserv  09:45:03    50174
>
> 1329244   2013-06-06  10  Archived    10:00:08    50174
>
> 1329268   2013-06-06  10  Archived    10:15:08    50174
>
> 1330286   2013-06-07  10  Archived    10:15:06    50174

I want to now what was the status of the VoerID on all first of months. so on 2013-05-01 status = N, on 2013-06-01 status = Reserv and from 2013-07-01 it is Archived.

So above is for one VoerID. I want to count the number of VoerID's per first of month, per last LOGID before the first of next month and per status

Finally if I get the information i want to edit it in MSExcel to a crosstable and Chart:

> 1-1-2013    1-2-2013    1-3-2013    1-4-2013    1-5-2013
>
> N 20  22  24  26  28
>
> B 23  21,5    20  18,5    17
>
> IN1   12  15  18  21  24
>
> IN2   15  7   14  18  25
>
> V 800 1000    1200    1400    1600
>
> Reserv    50  63  76  89  102
>
> Archived  100000  101220  102440  103660  104880

Comment: Check out this question: [For Loop in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069024/for-loop-for-sql)

Comment: @holbrookbw1: thats not helping... im new to this so i have no idea how to loop it

Answer (score 0):

Doing a cross join of all the days of the year, then grouping by that day.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT COUNT(l.VoerID) as COUNT, m.aDate, l.Status
FROM 
(
    SELECT Sub1.aDate, k.VoerID, MAX(k.LogID) AS LogID
    FROM DB.LogStatus k
    CROSS JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD('2013-01-01', INTERVAL units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i * 100 DAY) AS aDate -- return the first day of the year + all the numbers from 0 to 999
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units -- Select units of days
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens -- select tens
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) hundreds -- select hundreds
        WHERE  DATE_ADD('2013-01-01', INTERVAL units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i * 100 DAY) <= '2013-12-31' -- limit the dates to the days of the specific year
    ) Sub1
    WHERE k.Datum < Sub1.aDate -- This should give up multiple copies of record, one for each date where the d Datum is less that that date
    GROUP BY Sub1.aDate, k.VoerID -- GRoup by date and id, so getting the max log id for each date and id
) m
JOIN DB.LogStatus l
ON l.VoerID = m.VoerID AND l.LogID = m.LogID -- Join where log it is the max log id
WHERE status in ('x','y','z')
GROUP BY m.aDate, Status
```

EDIT - or for each month:-

```
SELECT COUNT(l.VoerID) as COUNT, m.aDate, l.Status
FROM 
(
    SELECT Sub1.aDate, k.VoerID, MAX(k.LogID) AS LogID
    FROM DB.LogStatus k
    CROSS JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD('2013-01-01', INTERVAL units.i MONTH) AS aDate -- return the first day of each month of the year
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11) units -- Select units of days
    ) Sub1
    WHERE k.Datum < Sub1.aDate -- This should give up multiple copies of record, one for each date where the d Datum is less that that date
    GROUP BY Sub1.aDate, k.VoerID -- GRoup by date and id, so getting the max log id for each date and id
) m
JOIN DB.LogStatus l
ON l.VoerID = m.VoerID AND l.LogID = m.LogID -- Join where log it is the max log id
WHERE status in ('x','y','z')
GROUP BY m.aDate, Status
```

Comment: that seems to work fine. can you break down year code so that i can learn what it does? I must say that the code is very slow though because of the immens table...

Comment: as the code per day takes way to much time (lost connection) is it possible to change the code to retrieving the information on the first day of the month?

Comment: Updated it to add a few comments. Are you only ever going to deal with a max of 365 days (ie a year)? If so the select to get the dates could get a smaller range of numbers and be a bit quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown.It could be that i want the info for the last five years or so, will that be possible? Or can yuou get it quicker if i only work with a max of 365 days?

Comment: And the Adata givs an image of BLOB... i know i can turn an option on to see the value but is that to fix within the code?

Comment: I must also add that the MaxLOG id is more important to dertermine the last Status. Now the code sees the last date (e.g. in juni), than selects the first of june and the corresponding status. However the last status is different from the status on the first of juni. (every VoerID ends with status 'archived') ALSO in case of 1 VoerID the code returns one row being the first day of the last month of logging. However i want to see the history of a VoerID: it's status on each first of the month. (count all the VoerID's with a certain status on the first of the mont.

Comment: Can be made to work for 5 years easily. Just change the inner select that generates the dates. There isn't a field called Adata, and aDate should be a date format field. As to your last point I am getting very confused over what you want. It might be easiest if you edit your original question with the structure of your tables (even better the table declare) and also some same data and the results you would want from that sample data.

Comment: I am a bit unsure about the second stage of your requirements ( _I want to count the number of VoerID's per first of month, per last LOGID before the first of next month and per status_ ). However I am not sure that the inner select to find the latest log id for each voerid for each month can be done more efficiently within SQL. It will generate a massive number of intermediate records (ie, for 5 years worth of months and 10000 voerids it will generate 6000000 intermediate records). Part of the problem is that the laest logid for a month could be from months earlier..

Comment: I know! difficult problem. I think i'll just do it manualy per month. Takes some time for the past years. After that i can monthly add the latest month.. Thanks for your help,understanding and patience :-)

Comment: No problem. Even a single months calculation is fairly complex