# How can INSERT INTO a table 300 times within a loop in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops, insert

I would like to insert a value retrieved from a counter in SQL and repeat it 300 times.

Something like:

```
DECLARE @Counter = 0;

-- BEGIN Loop 
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1 
    INSERT INTO tblFoo VALUES(@Counter)
-- REPEAT 300 times
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069024/syntax-of-for-loop-in-sql-server

Comment: In SQL, you should generally try to write set-based code, not procedural, step by step code. So, the SQLish thing to ask for is "how do I insert 300 rows into my table, where each row gets a unique value from the range 1-300?"

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You may try it like this:

```
DECLARE @i int = 0
WHILE @i < 300 
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    /* your code*/
END
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to write the same loop by setting the variable using `SET` ?

Comment: For many GUIDs use `insert into table_1 values(NEWID())`.

Answer (score 32):

```
DECLARE @first AS INT = 1
DECLARE @last AS INT = 300

WHILE(@first <= @last)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblFoo VALUES(@first)
    SET @first += 1
END
```

Answer (score 11):

I would prevent loops in general if i can, set approaches are much more efficient:

```
INSERT INTO tblFoo
  SELECT TOP (300) n = ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY n;
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/806cb/1/0)</kbd>

[**Generate a set or sequence without loops**](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim. Question: So here do I assume there is 300 sys.all_objects for sure? What if I wanted to insert even 10 thousand?

Comment: @pencilCake: i recommend to read the article i've posted. It shows other techniques as well. Actually you'll get problems with above approach with more than two thousand. I'd use a numbers-table.

Comment: On the other hand, if loops are not good idea in SQL, then I wonder why they introduced WHILE loops in T-SQL?

Comment: @pencilCake: there are things that aren't possible without loops or at least it isn't worth to implement a set based approach (which can take more time). So if you're doing this only once it might be sufficient to use a loop. But many people(programmers especially) are used with loops and keep using them in sql.

Answer (score 6):

In ssms we can use GO to execute same statement

**Edit**
This mean if you put

```
 some query

 GO n
```

Some query will be executed n times

Answer (score -2):

Found some different answers that I combined to solve similar problem:

```
CREATE TABLE nummer (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, num, text, text2);
WITH RECURSIVE
  for(i) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT i+1 FROM for WHERE i < 1000000)
INSERT INTO nummer SELECT i, i+1, "text" || i, "otherText" || i FROM for;
```

Adds 1 million rows with

- id increased by one every iteration
- num one greater then id
- text concatenated with id-number like: text1, text2 ... text1000000
- text2 concatenated with id-number like: otherText1, otherText2 ... otherText1000000