# Insert text concatenated with incrementing number sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2014

I would like to insert 1000 rows into a table. The data i would like to generate and insert is `TEXT0001` up to `TEXT1000`. So single digits need to have 3 leading zeroes (eg 1 -> 0001), 2 digits need 2 leading zeroes (2 -> 0091) etc.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21929070/2570277) answer on how to generate a range of numbers without using a loop and that works, but i need to add text infront of the number.

I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO projects
  SELECT TOP (1000) CONCAT("TEXT",  n) = ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY n;
```

but this gives an error - `incorrect syntax near =`.

I have read that using a `SET` based approach is the best way and i should avoid looping, but no actual examples to point me in the right direction.

How would i go about doing this please?

Comment: That's not valid SQL syntax. Functions arguments are passed *inside* the parentheses, not through an assignment operator. I don't know of any language that works this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some syntax correction and `FORMAT` function you have:

```
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT TOP 1000 'TEXT' + FORMAT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), '0000') AS n
FROM sys.all_objects
ORDER BY n -- it is a zero-padded varchar suitable for order-by
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need below

```
INSERT INTO projects
  SELECT TOP (1000) "TEXT" + right('0000',cast ((ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])) as varchar),4)
  FROM sys.all_objects ;
```

Comment: Thanks @Zaynul. How would i format the generated number as 4 digits. For example instead of 1 i need 0001.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend keeping `concat()` and fixing the syntax:

```
INSERT INTO projects (<column name here>)
  SELECT TOP (1000) CONCAT('TEXT', 
                           FORMAT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), '0000')) as n
  FROM sys.all_objects
  ORDER BY n;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Would this format single digits eg 1 as 0001?

Comment: Order by n means TEXT1, TEXT10, TEXT11 and so on