# Sybase. Break or continue inside of a for loop

Tags: t-sql, for-loop, sybase, procedure, continue

I'm writing Sybase procedure and ran into a problem: how to break inside of a for loop. It just gives me syntax error. Is it possible to skip the current row and go to the next one in for loop?

```
for TmpUserEvents as TmpUserCursorEvents dynamic scroll cursor for
  select
    *
  from
    test
do

  if flag = 1 then 
    continue; --break;
  end if;

end for;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax of for-loop in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069024/syntax-of-for-loop-in-sql-server)

Comment: T-SQL does not have a for loop. You will need to use `while`, `break` and `continue` http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/X51638.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: it is possible to continue for loop while executing.

```
for TmpUserEvents as TmpUserCursorEvents dynamic scroll cursor for
  select
    *
  from
    test
do
   lbl:
   loop
    if condition = 1 then
      leave lbl;
    end if;
   end loop lbl;
end for;
```