# Looping within SQL(ite) SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite, loops

The following SQLite query works:

```
SELECT Name,
(CASE 
WHEN P1=1 THEN 1 
WHEN P2=1 THEN 2 
WHEN P3=1 THEN 3 
WHEN P4=1 THEN 4 
WHEN P5=1 THEN 5 
ELSE NULL
END) AS Col
FROM table
```

but is there a way to `loop` then `WHEN` statements? Following [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069024/syntax-of-for-loop-in-sql-server) I tried:

```
SELECT Nachname, Vorname,
(CASE 
DECLARE @i int = 0
  WHILE @i < 5 BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    WHEN P@i=1 THEN @i 
  END
END) AS Col
FROM table
```

but this didn't work, saying: `error in statement: near "@i": syntax error`.

For full information I am applying this statement through a `sqldf` function on `R`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `P1` through to `P5` are column names. They are either empty or have a 1 as value.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no mechanism to create column names dynamically.

You have to list all columns by hand, or create the SQL query dynamically from your program.