# While loop with if statements in SQL not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, while-loop

I am new in using loop in SQL Server. I just wanted to ask why my code is not working? I am trying to have if statements within a loop and it will continue to process until it gets what it wanted.  Thanks for any response!

```
DECLARE @SubjectCategoryID bigint
DECLARE @ParentID bigint
DECLARE @EntityID bigint
DECLARE @isLocation int
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (ParentID bigint, isLocation int) 
DECLARE @projectCodesTable TABLE (Contingency nvarchar(max), Provincial nvarchar(max), HQAdmin nvarchar(max))    
DECLARE @count int

Select @SubjectCategoryID = SubjectCategoryID, @EntityID = EntityID  from t_Project WHERE Code = '1000296'
SET @count = 0
SET @isLocation = 0

WHILE (@isLocation = 1)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM @tempTable
    IF @SubjectCategoryID = 150     -- Village
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tempTable
            SELECT CommunityID, IsLocation from t_Loc_Village WHERE VillageID = @EntityID

        Select @EntityID = ParentID, @isLocation = isLocation From @tempTable
        SET @SubjectCategoryID = 140
    END
    ELSE IF @SubjectCategoryID = 140    --- Community
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tempTable
            SELECT CityTownID, IsLocation from t_Loc_Community WHERE CommunityID = @EntityID

        Select @EntityID = ParentID, @isLocation = isLocation From @tempTable
        SET @SubjectCategoryID = 135
    END
    ELSE IF @SubjectCategoryID = 135    --- City/Town
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tempTable
            SELECT ProvinceID, IsLocation from t_Loc_CityTown WHERE CityTownID = @EntityID

        Select @EntityID = ParentID, @isLocation = isLocation From @tempTable
        SET @SubjectCategoryID = 130
    END
    ELSE IF @SubjectCategoryID = 130    --- Province
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tempTable
            SELECT RegionalOfficeID, IsLocation from t_Loc_Province WHERE ProvinceID = @EntityID

        Select @EntityID = ParentID, @isLocation = isLocation From @tempTable
        SET @SubjectCategoryID = 210
    END
    ELSE IF @SubjectCategoryID = 210    --- Regional Office
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tempTable
            SELECT CountryID, IsLocation from t_RegionalOffice WHERE RegionalOfficeID = @EntityID

        Select @EntityID = ParentID, @isLocation = isLocation From @tempTable
        SET @SubjectCategoryID = 100
    END
    ELSE IF @SubjectCategoryID = 100    --- Country
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tempTable
            SELECT 0, IsLocation from t_Loc_Country WHERE CountryID = @EntityID

        Select @EntityID = ParentID, @isLocation = isLocation From @tempTable
        SET @SubjectCategoryID = 0
    END
END

Select * from @tempTable
```

Comment: Could you provide some example data from each of your tables: `t_Loc_Village` etc?

Comment: Where is @isLocation getting value of 1 for the control to go inside the WHILE loop?

Comment: @ShaneHaw, all those tables has LocationID, ParentID and isLocation columns. When I found the data in a particular table using the LocationID, the corresponding ParentID would be the new LocationID (@entity value) and will be used to search it to other tables.. Its like hierarchichal level., I am finding the location till it reaches the location where isLocation = 1.

Comment: @BijuP, I am setting the value of isLocation between each if and else if statements..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will not enter the while loop because you have set `isLocation=0` in the beginning and checking `while(isLocation=1).` Try changing your while loop logic. Use `GOTO` or simulate a `do while` loop. Please refer:[Do while loop in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487546/do-while-loop-in-sql-server-2008) for further information.

Comment: I think I set the isLocation = 0 before the while loop. See my code for reference.

Comment: Exactly the reason why your loop won't start execution. If you set `isLocation=0` and set `while(isLocation=1)`, it'll find isLocation as 1 and not execute the loop.

Comment: Sorry but may I ask if the condition inside while(condition) is the condition wherein it says that continue the loop till it gets isLocation = 1? Am I right?

Comment: Yup. It means that till the loop finds `isLocation` to be `1`, it should run the loop.