# Looped insert statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, sql-insert

Any help that can be provided would be much appreciated.

I have the following two tables

TS_DEF_TRADER:

```
DEF_TRADER_ID  MANAGER_CD       INV_CLASS_CD    TRADER_CD
------         -------          ----------      ---------
101            HARRIT           EQTY            MMGR_DT
108            NAIDON           EQTY            MMGR_DT
123            MLONDG           EQTY            MMGR_DT
```

and PDF_USER_GROUP:

```
GRP_CD                    USER_CD       
------                    -------          
STANLIB_MULTI_MANAGER     HARRIT           
STANLIB_MULTI_MANAGER     NAIDON           
STANLIB_MULTI_MANAGER     MLONDG 
STANLIB_MULTI_MANAGER     FARRYM
STANLIB_MULTI_MANAGER     HOLMEM
```

What I want to do is create some kind of a looped SQL insert statement (if that's the right terminology) that will check PDF_USER_GROUP and if there is a USER_CD with GRP_CD = STANLIB_MULTI_MANAGER that is missing from TS_DEF_TRADER. If any anything is missing then it will insert the relevant row.

I've written the below statement:

```
declare @DefTraderID INT
declare @Mgr varchar(200)
set @DefTraderID = (select MAX(DEF_TRADER_ID) + 1  from TS_DEF_TRADER)
set @Mgr = (select min(USER_CD) from PDF_USER_GROUP where not exists 
(select * from TS_DEF_TRADER where 
TRADER_CD = 'MMGR_DT' and 
INV_CLASS_CD = 'EQTY' and
TS_DEF_TRADER.MANAGER_CD = PDF_USER_GROUP.USER_CD)
and GRP_CD = 'STANLIB_MULTI_MANAGER'  and USER_CD not in ('MMGR_DT', 'SLIB_INDEX'))


insert into TS_DEF_TRADER (DEF_TRADER_ID,MANAGER_CD,INV_CLASS_CD, TRADER_CD)
values (@DefTraderID,@Mgr, 'EQTY', 'MMGR_DT')
```

If I run this manually myself twice, I get the following result which is what I want:

```
DEF_TRADER_ID  MANAGER_CD       INV_CLASS_CD    TRADER_CD
------         -------          ----------      ---------
101            HARRIT           EQTY            MMGR_DT
108            NAIDON           EQTY            MMGR_DT
123            MLONDG           EQTY            MMGR_DT
124            FARRYM           EQTY            MMGR_DT
125            HOLMEM           EQTY            MMGR_DT
```

If I were to run it a third time this would happen:

```
DEF_TRADER_ID  MANAGER_CD       INV_CLASS_CD    TRADER_CD
------         -------          ----------      ---------
101            HARRIT           EQTY            MMGR_DT
108            NAIDON           EQTY            MMGR_DT
123            MLONDG           EQTY            MMGR_DT
124            FARRYM           EQTY            MMGR_DT
125            HOLMEM           EQTY            MMGR_DT
126            NULL             EQTY            MMGR_DT
```

I need it to run by itself (ie: loop) and stop once when it needs to so we don't get the NULLs.

Comment: To summerize what you want, If there is a PDF_User_Group.User_CD that doesnt exist in TS_def_Trader.Manager_CD and the PDF_User_Group.GRP_CD == STANLIB_MULTI_MANGER . You want to add it to TS_Def_trader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a WHILE loop, and continually evaluate @Mgr for NULL:

```
declare @DefTraderID INT;
declare @Mgr varchar(200);

set @DefTraderID = (select MAX(DEF_TRADER_ID) + 1  from TS_DEF_TRADER);
set @Mgr = (select min(USER_CD) from PDF_USER_GROUP where not exists 
 (select * from TS_DEF_TRADER 
  where 
    TRADER_CD = 'MMGR_DT' and 
    INV_CLASS_CD = 'EQTY' and
    TS_DEF_TRADER.MANAGER_CD = PDF_USER_GROUP.USER_CD)
  and GRP_CD = 'STANLIB_MULTI_MANAGER'  
  and USER_CD not in ('MMGR_DT', 'SLIB_INDEX'));


WHILE (@Mgr IS NOT NULL)
  BEGIN

   insert into TS_DEF_TRADER (DEF_TRADER_ID,MANAGER_CD,INV_CLASS_CD, TRADER_CD)
   values (@DefTraderID, @Mgr, 'EQTY', 'MMGR_DT');

    set @DefTraderID = (select MAX(DEF_TRADER_ID) + 1  from TS_DEF_TRADER);
    set @Mgr = (select min(USER_CD) from PDF_USER_GROUP where not exists 
     (select * from TS_DEF_TRADER 
      where 
        TRADER_CD = 'MMGR_DT' and 
        INV_CLASS_CD = 'EQTY' and
        TS_DEF_TRADER.MANAGER_CD = PDF_USER_GROUP.USER_CD)
      and GRP_CD = 'STANLIB_MULTI_MANAGER'  
      and USER_CD not in ('MMGR_DT', 'SLIB_INDEX'));

  END
```

With the obvious caveat that `@Mgr` ought to be NULL at some point otherwise you'll loop forever.

AFAIK there is no `DO..WHILE / REPEAT..UNTIL` construct in SqlServer, however you can dry up the duplicated evaluation of `@Mgr` + `@DefTrader` [with one of these workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487546/do-while-loop-in-sql-server-2008) ~GOTO :(

Also, it may be a good idea to reconsider the incrementing of @DefTrader, viz `(select MAX(DEF_TRADER_ID) + 1  from TS_DEF_TRADER)`, e.g. with an `IDENTITY` column or a locked counters pattern - at the moment, the code isn't concurrent-safe.

Comment: Thanks. Solutions work 100%. I agree with you with regards to the Identity column however the table is a system table so I don't want to add additional columns. DEF_TRADER_ID is a primary key however so duplicates shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Note that Lamak does have a good point, though - if at all possible, try and use a set-based approach to processing, as this will have performance and scalability benefits :-)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't need a loop at all, you can just do a single `INSERT` statement:

```
DECLARE @MaxDefTraderId INT

SELECT @MaxDefTraderId = MAX(DEF_TRADER_ID)
FROM TS_DEF_TRADER

INSERT INTO TS_DEF_TRADER(DEF_TRADER_ID, MANAGER_CD, INV_CLASS_CD, TRADER_CD)
SELECT  @MaxDefTraderId + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY USER_CD) DEF_TRADER_ID, 
        USER_CD MANAGER_CD,
        'EQTY' INV_CLASS_CD,
        'MMGR_DT' TRADER_CD
FROM PDF_USER_GROUP A
WHERE GRP_CD = 'STANLIB_MULTI_MANAGER'
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TS_DEF_TRADER
               WHERE MANAGER_CD = A.USER_CD)
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb3d1/4) with this. And the results are:

```
╔═══════════════╦════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ DEF_TRADER_ID ║ MANAGER_CD ║ INV_CLASS_CD ║ TRADER_CD ║
╠═══════════════╬════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╣
║           101 ║ HARRIT     ║ EQTY         ║ MMGR_DT   ║
║           108 ║ NAIDON     ║ EQTY         ║ MMGR_DT   ║
║           123 ║ MLONDG     ║ EQTY         ║ MMGR_DT   ║
║           124 ║ FARRYM     ║ EQTY         ║ MMGR_DT   ║
║           125 ║ HOLMEM     ║ EQTY         ║ MMGR_DT   ║
╚═══════════════╩════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Now, I need to warn you about the way you are calculating the `DEF_TRADER_ID`. You should be using an `IDENTITY` column instead of assigning the value this way. What happens when another user tries to insert values to that table?, you could be inserting duplicates ids.

Comment: Thanks. Solutions work 100%. I agree with you with regards to the Identity column however the table is a system table so I don't want to add additional columns. DEF_TRADER_ID is a primary key however so duplicates shouldn't be allowed.