# SQL + print common factors of two numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I feel really dumb because I could easily do this in java or C# with a for loop but I am new to SQL and I am having trouble figuring this out.  What I have so far is that I have declared two integer variables for the numbers I want to find the common factors for.  However with SQL from what I am reading I need to use a while loop to cycle throuh the numbers to find the common factors, am I on the right track?  After that I just want SQL server to print the common factors.  Here is the code I have so far...

```
DECLARE @num1 int = 10;
DECLARE @num2 int = 20;
DECLARE @count INT = 1;

WHILE @count < @num1
BEGIN
IF (@num % @count = ?)
PRINT 'common factors'
END
```

Am I at least on the right track here?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: SQL is designed for data stored in tables.  You can use the scripting language for other purposes, but it is not nearly as powerful as a language such as C# and not well-suited to this sort of problem.

Comment: Why on earth would you do it in SQL?

Comment: lol, sorry guys. Yes I am aggravated because its part of a my homework assignment, I breezed right through all the questions except this one. I am thinking the same thing.  Why do I need to learn this in SQL is beyond me cause I agree, why would a person do this in SQL.

Comment: At least you're honest about homework. Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487546/do-while-loop-in-sql-server-2008).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one without the loop:

```
declare @num1 int
declare @num2 int
declare @f varchar(4000)
select @num1 = 12, @num2 = 26, @f = ''

;with lv0 as (select 0 g union all select 0)
    ,lv1 as (select 0 g from lv0 a cross join lv0 b) -- 4
    ,lv2 as (select 0 g from lv1 a cross join lv1 b) -- 16
    ,lv3 as (select 0 g from lv2 a cross join lv2 b) -- 256
    ,tally (n) as (select row_number() over (order by (select null)) from lv3)
select @f = @f + ', ' + convert(varchar(4000),n)
from tally
where 
    n <= @num1
    and @num1 % n = 0
    and @num2 % n = 0
print stuff(@f, 1, 2, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, user3530547 links helped me figure it out. I kept the loop and got it working with this...

```
USE md0577283
DECLARE @num1 int = 10;
DECLARE @num2 int = 20;
DECLARE @count INT = 1;

WHILE @count < @num1
BEGIN
IF (@num1 % @count = 0 and @num2 % @count = 0)
PRINT @count
set @count = @count + 1
END
```