# Cannot execute SQL script by code, but executing in SSMS works

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssms

Following SQL-Script is saved in a file:

```
WHILE @@rowcount > 0
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP(100) t1 
    WHERE name >= 20000
END
```

For executing in my software, I read the file and then execute the script by following method:

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString, string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

So now my problem is that the script isn't executed correctly on the MSSQL server, the entries still exist. There are no exceptions at all.

If I run the script in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, the script is being executed without any problems.

What can cause this issue?

Comment: can you post `queryString` data?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't just do something like `DELETE FROM t1 WHERE name >= 2000`? Why the while loop?

Comment: I'm wary of `WHERE name >= 20000`, smells like maybe a collation/sort issue. Maybe even a data type problem.

Comment: can youtry to make it a SP, and call that? not sure how procedural T-SQL will execute from ADO.NET

Comment: You cannot be sure @@rowcount > 0 the first time, i suggest you change your logic to a do-while syntax  instead, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487546/do-while-loop-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: thanks for help works now, @@rowcount was 0 on the first run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with definition:

> `@@rowcount` returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.

Looks like `@@rowcount` equals to 0.

When creating new connection, this value defaults to 1, so it has to enter your loop, but maybe you deleted all rows satisfying `where` clause.

Another guess is: there are some operations, which affect 0 rows, so `@@rowcount` equals to 0 and your loop isn't entered.

You could inspect the above guesses by executing and retrieving results of below query:

```
SELECT @@rowcount [rowcount]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem

Answer (score 2):

When you run your statement from the app @@rowcount is equal to "0"
You have to initialize it first, like this:

```
SELECT 1;
WHILE @@rowcount > 0
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP(100) t1 
    WHERE name >= 20000
END
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Michał:

@@rowcount returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. If the number of rows is more than 2 billion, use ROWCOUNT_BIG. From microsoft docs.

You should perform DO WHILE operation if you want to delete big chunk of records:

```
DECLARE @iter INT;

SET @iter = 1;

WHILE @iter > 0 BEGIN BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DELETE TOP(100) t1 WHERE name >= 20000

SET @iter = @@ROWCOUNT;

COMMIT TRANSACTION; 

END
```